# Typing Variadic Tuple in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, types

So I'm trying to type hint a Tuple of Tuples where I have something like this:

```
from typing import List, Tuple
def foo(arg: Tuple[Tuple[int]]):
    for tpl in arg:
        for thing_id in tpl:
            # do stuff
```

Where there can be more than one tuple in the tuple of tuples and there can be more than one integer in the tuples but there should only ever be a tuple of tuples of integers. In other words, I want both of these to work:

```
foo(((1,),))

foo(((1,2,3),(4,5))) # doesn't pass the checker which expects length == 1
```

but this to fail

```
foo(((1,"x"),))
```

Now I can use lists:

```
def bar(arg: List[List[int]]):
    print(arg)
```

and everything works as expected. But I want to default the argument and would prefer not to have a mutable default argument. Nor is there any reason to use a mutable structure here. Any way to do this?

Comment: Tuples are semantically constant-length, so a list should be used here. You can have a mutable default argument with a default of `None`, and a check for `None` at the top of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple):

> To specify a variable-length tuple of homogeneous type, use literal ellipsis, e.g. `Tuple[int, ...]`.

Thus, your type annotation would be `Tuple[Tuple[int, ...], ...]`, for a variable-length tuple of variable-length tuples of ints.

If your only reason for specifying tuples in your annotation is that you don't want a mutable default argument, then it's probably more appropriate to specify a sequence of sequences, or an iterable of iterables, depending on what functionality you need:

```
arg: Iterable[Iterable[int]]=((1, 2), (3, 4))
```